# continue Kotlin coroutine job after cancellation

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to do a little word after a kotlin coroutine is cancelled. (I have a delay function inside this coroutine). by using threads, I can catch `InterruptedException` and do some work, then finish the thread. but with Kotlin coroutines, it cancels the job immediately after calling cancel, when execution reaches the delay function.

I know if I use `Thread.sleep` inside coroutine, it will do the job. but is there any better solution?
I want to continue job after cancellation, not run some code if job is canceled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`withContext(NonCancellable) { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#run-non-cancellable-block). Code run inside this context won't react to cancellation of the outer coroutine. That means that functions like `delay` won't throw `CancellationException`.

You can use this in combination with `try`/`finally` to run suspending code after coroutine cancellation.

In this example, the call to `delay` will delay the termination of the coroutine, and won't throw a `CancellationException`, even if the coroutine has been cancelled.

```kotlin
try {
    // do stuff
} finally {
    withContext(NonCancellable) {
        delay(1000)
    }
}
```

This mechanism is described in more detail in the [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#run-non-cancellable-block). If you want even more detail, I've also written a [longer article](https://medium.com/better-programming/when-naming-matters-more-than-functionality-bc3dc2a8d576) about how it works.

Note that you can't "un-cancel" the coroutine. Using `try`/`finally` in combination with `NonCancellable` is primarily intended for running cleanup tasks. The coroutine `Job` is still marked as cancelled, and the coroutine should still ensure that it eventually terminates.